# Callback function, how to increment number from object then add to sum property

Tags: javascript, object, callback

Where am i wrong? I want to increment firstNumber then I want sum result to be 2. When I tried to debug and I got error "x is not defined"

```
function main() {
    let object = {
        firstNumber: 1,
        sum: 0
    }
    secFun(x, object, firstFun)
    console.log(object.sum)
}

function firstFun(a) {
    a.firstNumber++;
    a.sum += a.firstFun;

}

function secFun(x, y, callback) {

    callback(x, y);
}
main();
```

Comment: the `x` in `secFun(x, object, firstFun)` has not been assigned - therefore it's not defined. - you should assign x something - and it seems you want to replace `x` with `object`, since `firstFun(a)` is being mutated

Answer (score 0):

Your `main()` function is calling secFun with parameter `x`, but you have not declared `x` within the function's scope.

In fact, you have not declared `x` anywhere.

```js
function main() {
  let object = {
    firstNumber: 1,
    sum: 0
  }

  // 'x' is not defined in local or global scope
  secFun(x, object, firstFun)

  console.log(object.sum)
}
```

In additon, your `secFun` function calls a callback with two parameters, but `firstFun` accepts only one parameter.

```js
function secFun(x, y, callback) {

    // calling 'callback' with two arguments
    callback(x, y);
}

// but firstFun accepts only one parameter
function firstFun(a) {

}
```

Comment: Thx for fast reaction. One more time txh a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  function firstFun(a) {
    a.firstNumber++;
    a.sum += a.firstNumber;

}

function secFun(x, callback) {

    callback(x);
}
   function main() {
    let object = {
        firstNumber: 1,
        sum: 0
    }
    secFun(object, firstFun)
    console.log(object)
}

main();
```

Comment: I got it. Thx a lot :)

Comment: that was a good answer @Hakob. Maybe a bit more explanation would have been helpful, like what was missing, what you changed, why it wasn't working, why it is working now, and so forth. But you DID get the solution!